# Passing HTML string with res.render's options. But html elements are is getting converted to html codes so text is getting rendered on the email/view

Tags: node.js, express

Creating the HTML string.

```
_.each(order.parcel.pieces, function (piece, index) {
    piecesHtmlText += '<div style="float: left;margin: 0px 10px;width: 150px;">'+
    '<p style="font-weight: bold;">Piece - '+index+'</p>'+

    '<p>Length:&nbsp; <span>'+piece.piece_length+' '+piece.length_unit+'</span></p>'+

    '<p>Width:&nbsp;&nbsp; <span>'+piece.piece_width+' '+piece.length_unit+'</span></p>'+

    '<p>Height:&nbsp; <span>'+piece.piece_height+' '+piece.length_unit+'</span></p>'+

    '<p>Content: <span>'+piece.content+'</span></p>'+

    '<p>Reason:&nbsp; <span>'+piece.reason+'</span></p>'+
    '</div>';
});
```

Rendering the html and sending an email. ()

```
res.render(path.resolve('modules/orders/server/templates/order-successful-email'),
{
    name: req.user.displayName,
    order: order,
    date: date+'/'+month+'/'+year,
    piecesHtmlText: piecesHtmlText,
    appName: config.app.title,
    invoice_url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/invoice/' + order._id

}, function (err, emailHTML) {
    console.log(emailHTML);
    var mailOptions = {
        to: req.user.email,
        from: config.mailer.from,
        subject: 'Order successful',
        html: emailHTML
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/parcels/' + order._id + '/stage5');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/parcels/' + order._id + '/stage5');
        }
    });

}
```

The HTML file:

```
<div style="color: #4d4d4d;margin-bottom: 50px;">
<p>Dear {{name}} </p>
<p>Your order <a href="{{invoice_url}}">{{order._id+""}}</a> has been placed successfully with {{shippingPartner}} on Date {{date}}. </p>
<p>Please ensure that your contact and address information is accurate for a smooth delivery experience.</p>
<table style="max-width: 500px;margin: auto;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://mara.whyable.com/modules/core/img/brand/logo.png" style="width: 100px;" />
        </td><!-- Column for logo. -->
        <td></td>
    </tr><!-- First row for logo -->
    <tr style="background-color: #30bee4;color: white;">
        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px;">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Package contents</p>
            <hr style="color: white;"/>
            {{piecesHtmlText}}
        </td>
    </tr><!-- Second row for pieces information -->
</table>
```

When I pass HTML string as an option to res.render, the `<` and `>` are converted into HTML codes. Ex &lt; etc

Is there a way I can pass HTML string as an option to res.render?

Thank you.

Comment: What template engine did you use? If you can post the content of `order-successful-email` too...

Comment: Not using any template engine. 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure? Because what [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) do is: it compiles your view/template against the data (locals) that you provides, and creates the final HTML output...

Comment: Yes. I am not using any template engine.

Comment: Yes. I am not using any template engine.
Does express has any default template engine?

I have an array of objects which I want to display. If I use Jade or Handlebars I can iterate the array and display those objects. But I am not using any template engine. So I cannot iterate inside an html file. 

So, I am iterating through the array and generating html string and passing that string as locals to the render function. render function is converting the "<" and ">" symbols to the &lt; and &gt;

Comment: AFAIK, `res.render()` will throw error if you haven't defined any view  engine before hand. You've probably mapped the `.html` extension to a template engine somewhere earlier in your app. Guessing from the `HTML` content the template engine is probably [`Mustache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) or [`Handlebars (hbs)`](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs)

Comment: `Handlebars` provides a way to [avoid HTML escaping](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) by using `triple-stash`. If you do use `Handlebars`, try replacing the `{{piecesHtmlText}}` with `{{{piecesHtmlText}}}`...